# std::uniform_int_distribution causes build to fail in release

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

When attempting to build my project in release in visual studio, I get the [following errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mBxN.png) in part of [a random number generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZkEB.png). The program compiles and builds fine in debug, but not release. Does anyone know of a way to fix this?

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: Are you using the same `/std:` setting in debug and release?

Comment: @Frank where can I view that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before C++17, you needed to have the angle brackets:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(1, 6);
```

Given the error is:

> Argument list is missing

you probably need to pass the right build settings to your compiler, both in release and debug.

Comment: Checked my properties tab and you're right, debug was on c++17 but release was still on the default c++14. Changing it seems to have fixed the problem, thanks for the help!